# Printing out to five decimal places using MIPS integer commands

Tags: assembly, printing, int, mips

So I am writing a program that should have the following requirements:

Write an assembly program that reads a series of integers from the console. Valid entries are between -110 and 120 (inclusive). If an entry is invalid, the entry is rejected and an error message is printed to the screen. Reading stops when a -467 is entered. After a -467 is entered, the program displays the number of entries, the sum of the entries, and the average of the entries to 5 decimal places using only MIPS Integer commands. There will be at least 3 subprograms. The first ‘read_int’ which receives no arguments in and returns the total and count of valid numbers read in the appropriate registers. The second ‘print_count_total’ which receives as arguments in the arguments returned by the first subprogram and has no arguments out. It output the count and total properly labeled to the screen. The third ‘print_average’ which receives as arguments in the arguments returned by the first subprogram and has no arguments out. It outputs the average of the numbers read to 5 decimal places using only integer commands.

I have everything working, but how would I print out the integer average to five decimal places? Like for example:

[image]

The integer average should have printed out as 71.**25000**.

This is my code:

```
###########################################################
#       Program Description
#
#
#  Reads integers from the keyboard and displays the total
#    number of entries, sum, and integer average
#  Reads until -1 is entered
#  Only accepts values between 10 and 99 (inclusive)
#
#
#  t0 = 0       # Total
#  t1 = 0       # Count
#  t2 = -110        # Min
#  t3 = 120     # Max
#  t4 = -467        # Stop
#
###########################################################
#       Register Usage
#   $t0  Running total
#   $t1  Entry count
#   $t2  Minimum value
#   $t3  Maximum value
#   $t4  Stop value
#   $t5  Entry (from user)
###########################################################
        .data
enter_p:  .asciiz "Enter a value between -110 and 120 (inclusive):  "
invalid_p:  .asciiz "Invalid value\n\n"
count_p:  .asciiz "\n\nNumber of entries:  "
total_p:  .asciiz "\nTotal:  "
average_p:  .asciiz "\nInteger average:  "
noentry_p:  .asciiz "\n\nNo valid values entered\n"

###########################################################
        .text
main:
    # Initialize values
    li $t0, 0       # Total
    li $t1, 0       # Count
    li $t2, -110        # Min value
    li $t3, 120     # Max value
    li $t4, -467        # Stop value

readLoop:
    # Get value
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, enter_p
    syscall         # Prompt for value
    li $v0, 5
    syscall         # Read entry

    # Validate value
    beq $v0, $t4, getResults
    blt $v0, $t2, entryInvalid
    bgt $v0, $t3, entryInvalid

    # If program gets here, the entry is valid
    add $t0, $t0, $v0   # Add entry to total
    addiu $t1, $t1, 1   # Increment counter

    b readLoop          # Loop

entryInvalid:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, invalid_p
    syscall         # Print error message

    b readLoop      # Go back and read more

getResults:
    beqz $t1, zeroEntries   # Prevent divide by 0

    # Display number of entries
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, count_p
    syscall         # Print 'count' string
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall         # Print count

    # Display total
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, total_p
    syscall         # Print 'total' string
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall         # Print total

    # Calculate and display average
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, average_p
    syscall         # Print 'average' string
    li $v0, 1
    div $a0, $t0, $t1   # Put results directly into $a0
    syscall         # Print average

    b mainEnd       # Done

zeroEntries:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, noentry_p
    syscall         # Print 'no entries' message

mainEnd:
    li $v0, 10      # End Program
    syscall
###########################################################
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To print the fractional part, multiply the division remainder by 10^5=100000 and divide again. Print it after a decimal point, taking care to use appropriate amount of zero padding.

Comment: Thank you for that, Jester. I understand your algorithm, but how would that look in actual code? And where in my program should that code be placed? I am assuming that it would need to be placed somewhere down there in the block of code where I *# Calculate and display average*. Thank you for the help.

Comment: These are quite simple steps that can be performed by instructions you already know. Which part is causing you headache?

Comment: I am pretty sure myself that I know the instructions that would perform the algorithm you suggested, but performing the neccessary steps in the correct order is what I am having trouble understanding. So does the division remainder get put in the HI or LO register? Thanks again, Jester.

Comment: `HI` is the remainder. You should have an instruction set reference handy to look up instructions and a debugger where you can try code for yourself.

Comment: Jester, so I attempted at doing "multiply the division remainder by 10^5=100000 and divide again" per your suggestion. Here is the code: http://imgur.com/u2msM6Q . What do you think about that part for now?